# Beam pattern for a linear array comprised of rectangular transducers

Tags: antenna, transducer

I am looking for the beam pattern of a linear array with uniform spacing, *d*, between *n* elements. 
I know for an array comprised of circular pistons it can be derived from

$$\frac{1}{n}\frac{\sin[n\pi\frac{d}{\lambda}(\sin\theta-\sin\theta_s)]}{\sin[\pi\frac{d}{\lambda}(\sin\theta-\sin\theta_s)]}$$

where \$\lambda\$ is the wavelength. And it is a narrowband system.
I appreciate if you can provide a reference book and describe how I can derive the beam pattern for the particular case of rectangular elements.

Comment: convolve the array gain with the element gain, simples

Comment: It's not working. I already did that. The above equation is the AF for a ULA which can steer the main lobe theta_s degree. multiplying it by a rectangular piston AF destroys the whole beam pattern and doesn't have any steering ability. At theta_s=0 it works well but for any steering angle, funny things happen.

Comment: I didn't say multiply, I said convolve, that is multiply the fourier transforms, then transform back.